# Where can I find Yaevinn for the quest "The Unforgiven"?

Tags: the-witcher

I tried to stay neutral at the bank robbery and ended up helping Siegfried (which, as I read, cannot be helped). Now I'm looking to side with the Scoia'tael in the quest "The Unforgiven", but I cannot find Yaevinn.

Online sources indicate that he should be at the refugee camp in the swamp, but I've checked and he isn't. There is, however, a pretty annoying Elf who likes to steal my Feainnewedd every time I talk to her.

So far I have checked these areas at each of the four major times of day:

- Vivaldi's house
- Refugee camp
- Druid's grove
- Elven ruins (sewers)

By the way, I'm trying to go for the neutral path, having already been through the Flaming Rose one. Please correct me if I'm going about this the wrong way. I tried talking to Velerad but he's not interested in doing much other than dice poker.

I'm starting to think that my save file is bugged. If anyone is interested, you can download my most recent save in a zip [here](http://min.us/mcNRDhs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through some (indecisive) searching and piecing things together, I've decided that **Yaevinn is actually unreachable if you help Siegfried in the bank robbery**. Having checked all reasonable areas, I'm fairly certain that this is the case. Otherwise, my save file must be bugged. As such, I just decided to go with Siegfried.

I will be accepting my own answer because I did state that I'd helped Siegfried, and I was unable to find this information elsewhere on the Web, so it may prove useful to others who are looking to side with Yaevinn under these circumstances.

If you're absolutely certain that Yaevinn is actually reachable after going with Siegfried in the bank robbery, please say where (or comment on the correct answer).

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to find Yaevinn at Golan Vivaldi's house in the Temple Quarter. He goes into hiding there after the bank robbery.

Comment: Thanks, but I just checked that at the four major times of day and he's not there. I'm starting to suspect that my save is bugged.